# Iterate through menu and make screenshots with index of directory with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, loops, selenium-chromedriver

This is the structure of the Menu with the xpath "/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[2]/ul".

```
1.1 li Element xpath "/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]"
1.2 li Element xpath "/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[2]"
1.2.1 li Element xpath "/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[2]/ul/li"
back_button xpath "/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[3]"
1.3 li Element xpath "/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[3]"
1.4 li Element xpath "/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[4]"
1.5 li Element xpath "/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[5]"
1.5.1 li Element xpath "/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[5]/ul/li[1]"
1.5.2 li Element xpath "/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[5]/ul/li[2]"
1.5.2.1 li Element xpath "/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[5]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]"
1.5.2.2 li Element xpath "/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[5]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[2]"
1.5.2.3 li Element xpath "/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[5]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[3]"
1.5.3 li Element xpath "/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[5]/ul/li[3]"
...
1.127 li Element xpath "/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[127]"
```

The menu is in an iframe with the xpath "/html/body/div[3]/div/iframe". There are ony 3 levels. The back_button works only inside the second level.

I tried this:

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

xpath_prefix = "/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[2]/ul/li"
back_button_xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[3]"

def take_screenshot(driver, index):
    driver.save_screenshot(f"{index}.png")

def click_next_li(driver, index):
    try:
        next_li = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"{xpath_prefix}[{index}]")
        next_li.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        take_screenshot(driver, index)
        return True
    except (NoSuchElementException, ElementNotInteractableException):
        return False

def go_back(driver):
    back_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, back_button_xpath)
    back_button.click()
    time.sleep(5)

index = 1
while click_next_li(driver, index):
    index += 1

go_back(driver)

index = 1
while click_next_li(driver, index):
    index += 1

# Switch back to the main frame
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

It manages to go to 2.1 but loops back to 1.1. Instead of going to 1.3 and so on. Where is the issue? Do I have to track the last visited element?

Comment: As per I understand the issue, fix is remove `index = 1` of second time in code. TRY BELOW `index = 1
while click_next_li(driver, index):
    index += 1

go_back(driver)

while click_next_li(driver, index):
    index += 1`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't saw hat. NOw it works for the 1. level. 1.2.1 gets no click and when the driver hits 1.5 it closes the driver.